# How do I format a string while using a BindingSource?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

Technology: Visual Studio 2008 .NET, Winforms

```
bsTransactions.DataSource = Transactions.Tables[2];
bsnTransactions.BindingSource = bsTransactions;

txtTransOverrideDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsTransactions, "TransactionDate", true,DataSourceUpdateMode.Never, "", "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Currently, I'm getting an error saying that the string wasn't a recognized DateTime string. Despite the fact that if I get the column type from

```
 Transactions.Tables[2].Rows[0]["TransactionDate"].DataType.ToString();
```

returns "System.DateTime" and the actual value looks like "1/23/2010 12:00:00 AM"

I'm trying to format a string that currently looks like "1/23/2010 12:00:00 AM" to only show the date.

The catch is, there's a BindingSourceNavigator being use, so just applying the formatting to the textbox after the fact only applies to the first value, but not any others that are navigated to using the bindingNavigator.

I have a feeling that using the "bsTransactions" to applies bindings to the textbox, it's changing the datatype, hence it not being recognized as a DateTime.

Comment: Yes. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem.  The code you're showing works.

Comment: As it turns out, I'm a dummy. I actually have two fields that I needed to do this on, and while I was looking at field #1, I was working on field #2....It does work as LarsTech mentioned. However, there were some changes needed to make it work. ie: the format string was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txtTransOverrideDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsTransactions, "TransactionDate", true,DataSourceUpdateMode.Never, "", "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I made changes in the original post to mimic this, but this is the answer.

Comment: Christian: Thanks for this. I'm just discovering this now after a very long search for a solution to this problem. I found many examples of how to format output from a dataset[datatable] to a textbox directly but nothing via a binding source until I found your post. Thanks again.